# Is it possible to see the results of multiple find operations at once in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse it is possible to browse through a stack of previous search results. In IDEA it seems I can only have one set of search results, and if I want to do another one, I'm destined to lose the first set. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you're using the 'Find in Path' method to search (CRTL + shift + F on windows) then you'll see in the dialog box a checkbox near the bottom right labelled 'Open in new tab'. Checking that checkbox allows you to have multiple search results each in their own tab.

Comment: There is also a Pin option for the results tab an its context menu.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that checkbox.